# Multiple (and differents) crons?

Tags: cron, maintenance-mode

In a normal production webiste, there are many tasks that need to be done via crontab, but lets say you *dont want all of these tasks* to run on every cron.

For example, i would love to have:

1. A cron that run once a day, for the 'normal' maintenance (updates checks, for example)
2. B cron that runs every 15 minutes, to send newsletters (from simplenews)
3. C cron that run twice a day, that pull data from a view (json view) and write down a json file on the server (for a geomapping service with lots of data that doenst need a real-time sincronyzation).

Actually, i have a unique cron that do the A, B and C tasks on every run, every 15 minutes; so i created 2 php scripts that bootstrap drupal, one send the emails, and the other one cache the geomapping file.. it works, but is pretty a *manual*  way that i dont like too much.

What is the best practice to set different crons, get all the modules hook_cron, and assign them **only** to a specific cron?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a module for that (tm):

http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron

Have a look at http://2bits.com/drupal-performance/improving-performance-drupals-cron-using-elysia-cron-module.html for more information about it.

Comment: Thanks man, exactly what i was looking for! Strange things i googled around many times without results -.-